# jquery append in separate div

Tags: jquery, append

I have a gallery where the title should be my caption.
Now I want the caption outside of the gallery in a separate div.
This is how I go trough the images to get the title.
but how do I append the title of the displayed image into a separate div?

```
var appendCaptions = function(){
        // cycle through each child
        slider.children.each(function(index){
            // get the image title attribute
            var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');
            // append the caption
            if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {
                $(this).append(title);
            }
        });
    }


<ul class="bxslider">
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="Happy tre333es" /></li>
              <li><img src="images/1.jpg" title="Happy treeffees" /></li>
            </ul>
<div class='title'></div>
```

I want the title displayed inside of the div title; the slider I am using is the bxslider

Comment: You have to simply get the element by proper selector and append to it:) eg. $("#myDiv").append(title);

Comment: i tried that but then i get all the titles in the div but i want only the title of the displayed image

Comment: what do you mean by displayed image

Comment: the image which is diplayed in the slider

Comment: and whats the problem in ur code occuring?

Comment: the captions are displayed as a child of the slider! but i want the title ouside of the slider inside a seperate div

Comment: i have updated my code try that

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the loop as you are in each iterator, so try:

```
var appendCaptions = function(){
        // cycle through each child
        slider.children.each(function(index){
            // get the image title attribute
            if( $(this).is(':visible')){
            var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');
            // append the caption
            if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {
                $('#myDiv').append(title);
                return false;
            }
          }
       });
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me! it makes the slider loading all the time!

Comment: and please be more precisely in adding the questions :)

Comment: ok seems like there is something still not working! i get the title of the first image but when i go to the next image the title is not changing!

Comment: i am using the bxslider! and i modify the jquery of bxslider!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
$("#myTitleDiv").html(title);
```

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) is pretty great.

Comment: no with this i get all the titles in the div and not the one of the displayed image

Answer (score 0):

Place some HTML.

I assume you're trying to:

- get the title of every single slider image,
- append the title to the each div which is container of this image.

Maybe try something like this:

```
var appendCaptions = function(){
        // cycle through each child
        slider.children.each(function(index){
        // get the image title attribute
        var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');
        // append the caption
        if (title != undefined && ('' + title).length) {
            $(this).parents("div.singleImgContainer").append(title);
        }
    });
}
```

This will find div with class singleImgContainer and will place the title in it.

Comment: with this no title is displayed at all! i tried $(this).parents().find('.titles').append(title);
but then i get again all titles!

Comment: Code is ok, but my assumption was wrong but it's because of lack of details in your question.